# Riemann mapping theorem, prelim question

Tags: complex-analysis

Back at it again with another prelim question. Let $A\subsetneq \mathbb{C}$ be simply connected. For each fixed $z,w\in A$ define

\begin{align} \mathcal{C}(A,w,z)=\sup\{\lvert f'(w)\rvert :\,\text{f is an analytic map of A to itself and}\,\,f(w)=z\}.\end{align}
Show that $\mathcal{C}(A,w,z)<\infty$. I think I have a proof but I want to see that it is correct and I also have a more general question about this number.

Fix $z,w\in A$ and let $f:A\rightarrow A$ be analytic with $f(w)=z$. We will find a $C<\infty$ such that $\lvert f'(w)\rvert\leq C$. By the Riemann Mapping Theorem, there exist analytic, bijective maps $k:\mathbb{D}\rightarrow A$ and $h:A\rightarrow \mathbb{D}$ such that $k(0)=w$ and $h(z)=0$. Now define $g=h\circ f\circ k$ and note that $g$ is an analytic map of the unit disk to itself with $g(0)=0$. Thus $\lvert g'(0)\rvert \leq 1$ by the Schwarz Lemma.

On the other-hand, by the chain rule, $g'(\zeta)=k'(\zeta)h'(f(k(\zeta)))f'(k(\zeta))$, so $g'(0)=k'(0)h'(z)f'(w)$. Thus, $\lvert f'(w)\rvert \leq C:=\frac{1}{\lvert k'(0)h'(z)\rvert}<\infty$, since $k'(0),h'(z)\neq 0$ due to injectivity. Note that the constant $C$ is independent of $f$, so we are done.

Does $\mathcal{C}(A,w,z)$ have any sort of significance or prominence in conformal mapping? Also are we guarunteed that the quantity $\mathcal{C}(A,w,z)$ is attained by some $f:A\rightarrow A$ conformal? It seems like that would make sense but I can't think of why.

Comment: define $f=h^{-1} \circ k^{-1}, f(w)=z, f'(w)=\frac{1}{k'(0)h'(z)}$ - you can always guarantee Riemann maps with $h'(z)>0, k'(0)>0$ so for those $f'(w)>0$ so is the $C$ you want

Comment: As an idea for your last question: this looks like a case for Montel's theorem applied to the uniformly bounded family $\{f:A\to A~|~f\textrm{ holomorphic and }f(w)=z\}$.